# fail2ban jail not being enabled

Tags: server, fail2ban, nextcloud, debian-stretch

I want to secure my debian server with Fail2Ban v0.9.6. So I created the following entries in the newly created file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```
[nextcloud-trusted]
enable = true
port = http,https
logpath = /var/nextcloud/data/nextcloud.log
maxretry = 3

[sshd]
enable = true
```

The corresponding filter definition in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nextcloud-trusted.conf` looks like this

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^.*\"remoteAddr\":\"<HOST>\".*Trusted domain error.*$
```

Now I would expect fail2ban to enable both jails at startup, but only the jail `sshd` is being enabled but not `nextcloud-trusted` and I can't figure out why. Even adding the paramter `backend = auto` to the `nextcloud-trusted` jail doesn't change anything (as it was suggested in some other answers).

Comment: Probably your `nextcould-trusted.conf` is missing [INCLUDES] section?
Also, maybe this will be useful: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/fail2ban-filters/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I wrote `enable` instead of `enabled`. That was the error.